# Is it possible in React Select to select something but keep the input blank?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

so I'm using React Select to select a list of places but I want to render them out beneath the select box as per my designs

so I'm selecting with React Select then adding to my state and mapping over. all is well.

the problem is, I don't want the selected thing to be added to the select box, I just want to leave it blank indicating that another value can be selected. I know it isn't really designed for this but was wondering if there was maybe a work around for it?

Comment: Not totally sure what you're trying to do exactly, but maybe you can save the selected item in state and then explicitly set the value of the select box to null. If you set up a codepen or something with an example, I might be able to help more.

Comment: Why you can't use there desigen of `isMulti` prop?

Comment: @HagaiHarari isMulti is good but it wont fit to my design specs

Comment: @georgedum let me try and create that now, one sec

Comment: @georgedum see this: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-wind-dln29?file=/src/App.js

Comment: ah figured it out. apparently you can add this as a prop: `value={null}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass `value={null}` to `<Select value={null}` and it wont set a value if anyone ever needs this in the future :)

Comment: lol that's exactly what I tried. https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-dawn-k0ysm

Nice work!